# PostgreSQL Permissions in Amazon RDS using Flyway Migration

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, flyway

I'm trying to get Flyway up and running for database source control of Postgres and am running into permissions issues.

Scenario:
New database on AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance.

- RDS superuser configured is "postgres" and I login as that to create the db and setup roles.
- I create a "flyway_user" account that I want the flyway tool to use and add it to the rds_superuser role.
- I create a couple schemas that flyway will manage and GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA to the "flyway_user" account.

When I then try to have flyway do a migration to create tables in these schemas I get an error of permission denied.  So what am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is quite old, but it shows up on Google and I've been having the same issues.

While these permissions might be a little too loose, this is what I've done to get Flyway migrating correctly when using RDS and a flyway specific user.

```
-- Create a Migrator Role
CREATE ROLE schema_migrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <database> TO schema_migrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA <schema> TO schema_migrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <schema> TO schema_migrator;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO schema_migrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA <schema> TO schema_migrator;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO schema_migrator;

-- Assign Role to flyway_user
GRANT schema_migrator TO flyway_user;
```

Comment: Thanks this helped immensely. I'd like to note that if you want to change permissions of other users with the migration user as well (e.g. in before/afterMigration scripts) you will need to add `WITH GRANT OPTION` to the GRANT ALL and ALTER commands and `WITH ADMIN OPTION` to the GRANT schema_migrator command.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you have to set the password for the postgres user to flyway as flyway automatically uses that use. Based on http://flywaydb.org/contribute/code/database.html